# Get GeoLocation in Blazor Server .NET 8

Tags: geolocation, blazor-server-side, javascript-interop

New to Blazor, so apologies if this is just bad code, but I am having issues with getting Javascript Interop to work here.  I am attempting to get the user to allow GeoLocation from a button onSubmit.  I am not receiving any errors, but I'm also not getting the JSInvokable methods to fire.

My Blazor page:

```
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
 @inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime

<EditForm EditContext="editContext" FormName="MessageForm" OnValidSubmit="@GetLoc">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" data-callback="onSubmit" data-action="GetLocation">Share Your Location to Load</button>
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private DotNetObjectReference<Dealer>? dotNet;
    private double geoLat, geoLong;

    private async Task GetLoc()
    {
        try
        {
            dotNet = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
            var result = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("blazorGetLocation", dotNet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exceptions
        }
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void ReturnLocation(double latitude, double longitude)
    {
        geoLat = latitude;
        geoLong = longitude;
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public void ReturnError(string errorMessage)
    {
        geoLat = 0;
        geoLong = 0;
    }

    private EditContext? editContext;

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public GeoLocation? geoLoc { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        geoLoc ??= new();
        editContext = new(geoLoc);
    }
}
```

My Javascript:

```
window.returnLocation = function (dotNet) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            dotNet.invokeMethodAsync('ReturnLocation', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        });
    } else {
        dotNet.invokeMethodAsync('ReturnError', 'Some error text.');
    }
};
```

Comment: Does it hit the calls to invokeMethodAsync in your JavaScript code?  I am having a similar issue in Blazor .net 8 (except using static methods).  It worked in .net 6 but does not arrive in the [JSInvokable] code in .net 8.

Comment: I am hitting a breakpoint in the javascript code, but not back in my JSInvokable methods.  It's like the code just stops midway but never triggers an error.

It's interesting that it works in .NET 6, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading (and re-reading) everything I could find on this, the issue came from where I was trying to call JsRuntime.InvokeAsync method.

By using @rendermode InteractiveServer and calling "var result = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync("blazorGetLocation", dotNet)" from within the OnAfterRenderAsync override, the code works fine now.